# Android Device Admin dialogue not showing up - Auto declined

Tags: android, dialog, admin, device-policy-manager

I'm trying to implement locking the screen with my app.
I've worked my way through google documentation and studied the sample.

When i call this

```
    void getAdmin(){
    Intent activateDeviceAdminIntent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
        activateDeviceAdminIntent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mPolicy.getPolicyAdmin());
        activateDeviceAdminIntent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                getResources().getString(R.string.AdminReceiverDescr));
        startActivityForResult(activateDeviceAdminIntent, REQ_ACTIVATE_DEVICE_ADMIN);
}
```

The dialogue doesn't show up (maybe it flashes a little, can't say for sure), it just jumps in my onResult routine and result is "not granted". But my app afterwards shows up in the list in settings/security/device admins and if i enable admin rights manually it locks my screen like a charm.

I've added the permission

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"

as well as

receiver ... android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"

to my manifest.

Does anyone have a clue what i may have missed?
Thx in advance!

Comment: you must also add the activity to your manifest

Comment: I have all my activities added to the manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem in my manifest: you have to specify the receiver subclass with a $ sign.

Example:
android:name="com.exampl.PolicyClass$PolicyReceiver"